# How to work with node module 'windows' to read clients registry

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, registry

I'm having the same problem with the question: [Error when import of node module 'windows' in electrons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74959948/error-when-import-of-node-module-windows-in-electrons).

Can anybody explain to me how to make this module work (https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows)? I'm new to node.js.
Thank you.